# Android: Reload Activity with new integer values

Tags: android, imageview

I'm creating a game which uses an array of images named lvl1p1. These images were loaded and used on an ImageView. Now, my problem is when the player answer it correctly, the ImageView won't load the next array of image lvl1p2.

here is my code:

```
package com.bd.mpg;

import java.util.Arrays;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class GameWindow extends Activity {

    //declarations
    String ans;
    boolean answer;
    TypedArray imgs;
    public int imgarray;
    public int counter;
    public int wincount;
    final Context con = this;
    boolean check;
    public int totalstar;
    String debugtext;
    String debugtexta;
    String[] lvl1p1ANS;
    ImageView img;
    ImageView imgbat;
    Button submit;
    EditText answerfield;
    TextView debug;

    //main code
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_game_window);

        lvl1p1ANS = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.lvl1p1ANS);
        img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagegame);
        imgbat = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submitbtn);
        answerfield = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.answertb);
        debug = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.leveltitle);


        //level setter
                if (wincount == 0){
                    imgarray = R.array.lvl1p1;
                } else if (wincount == 1) {
                    imgarray = R.array.lvl1p2;
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(GameWindow.this, 
                            "Beta!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


        //item_load_up

        imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(imgarray);
        img.setImageResource(imgs.getResourceId(9, 0)); 




        //image_click
        img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
         {

            public void onClick(View v) 
             {
                 counter++; //energy counter
                 debugtext = String.valueOf(counter);
                 imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(imgarray);
                 if (counter == 8) {
                     imgbat.setImageResource(R.drawable.b1r);
                     img.setImageResource(imgs.getResourceId(1, 0));
                     Toast.makeText(GameWindow.this, 
                            debugtext, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 } else if (counter == 7) {
                     imgbat.setImageResource(R.drawable.b2r);
                     img.setImageResource(imgs.getResourceId(2, 0));
                     Toast.makeText(GameWindow.this, 
                            debugtext, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 } else if (counter == 6) {
                     imgbat.setImageResource(R.drawable.b3r);
                     img.setImageResource(imgs.getResourceId(3, 0));
                     Toast.makeText(GameWindow.this, 
                            debugtext, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 } else if (counter == 5) {
                     imgbat.setImageResource(R.drawable.b4y);
                     img.setImageResource(imgs.getResourceId(4, 0));
                     Toast.makeText(GameWindow.this, 
                            debugtext, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 } else if (counter == 4) {
                     imgbat.setImageResource(R.drawable.b5y);
                     img.setImageResource(imgs.getResourceId(5, 0));
                     Toast.makeText(GameWindow.this, 
                            debugtext, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 } else if (counter == 3) {
                     imgbat.setImageResource(R.drawable.b6y);
                     img.setImageResource(imgs.getResourceId(6, 0));
                     Toast.makeText(GameWindow.this, 
                            debugtext, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 } else if (counter == 2) {
                     imgbat.setImageResource(R.drawable.b7g);
                     img.setImageResource(imgs.getResourceId(7, 0));
                     Toast.makeText(GameWindow.this, 
                            debugtext, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 } else if (counter == 1){
                     imgbat.setImageResource(R.drawable.b8g);
                     img.setImageResource(imgs.getResourceId(8, 0));
                     Toast.makeText(GameWindow.this, 
                            debugtext, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 } else {   //game_over_code
                     Toast.makeText(GameWindow.this, 
                                "Game Over!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     Intent go = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GameOver.class);
                     startActivity(go);
                 }
             }

         });

    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {

        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            ans = answerfield.getText().toString();
            debugtexta = String.valueOf(imgarray);
            if (ans.equals("FLASHLIGHT")){

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(GameWindow.this, 
                    "bugok!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
             }
});



    debug.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
     {

            public void onClick(View v) 
             {
                Toast.makeText(GameWindow.this, 
                        debugtexta, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
     });
    }
  }
```

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have too much code in your `onCreate` function.

Move all the code that sets values out of `onCreate` function and put in a new function.

Now you can call that function once in `onCreate` and later on when you want to restart values again.

Comment: oh okay, i'll do that, thanks, also the level setter part isn't working. Right now i'm finding ways to reload my ImageView with the new integer value if wincount increments. thanks again

Comment: If it fixes your problem then you can accept the answer.

Comment: gee thanks dude, it greatly lowers the app size of my game. I also found where the problem is. thanks again